# WebStorm 2016.2.0 is adding two space-bars instead of a tab character

Tags: webstorm

Currently when I edit some file in WebStorm 2016.2.0 and I press tab, WebStrom is actually adding 2 space bars. There should be a setting somewhere in the editor for this. I want to have tab character instead the default 2 space-bars, my question is how to do this ?

Comment: Indentation (tabs or spaces; how many) -- this is a per file type setting. You can find it in `Settings/Preferences | Editor | Code Style | FILE TYPE`. HINT: you can use search box to narrow your search scope (e.g. by using `indent` as search term).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change this option for each of the supported languages at:

`Settings > Editor > Code Style > [Choose your language] > Tabs and Indents > Use tab character`

Or you can add a [`.editorconfig`](http://editorconfig.org/) file in the root of your project to set your preferences globally. All that you'll need to write in it is `indent_style = tab`

Comment: Tnx this is the correct way to do it. My problem was that in the source folder of the project there was `.editorconfig` which was overriding the preferences `Settings > Editor > Code Style > [Choose your language] > Tabs and Indents > Use tab character`